# How to describe type scroll events?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events, scroll

I added listener on scroll, and tried to use event. How can I describe type instead of any ?

React 16.8.6
Tpescript 3.4

```
const Component: FC<IProps> = ({ children, scrollOffset, getScrollTop, videoListScrollUpdate }) => {
    const scroller = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (scrollOffset && scroller.current) {
            scroller.current.scrollTop = scrollOffset
            return
        }
        if (getScrollTop && scroller.current) {
            scroller.current.addEventListener('scroll', (e: any) => getScrollTop(e.target.scrollTop))
        }
    }, [])

}
```

Answer (score 31):

> You can use **`(e: React.UIEvent<HTMLElement>)`**. Described under the [UIEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#ui-events) from SyntheticEvents.

That said, I would advise against using `useRef` within a `useEffect`. [It's tricky](https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780) to determine whether `useEffect` was re-called and `scroller.current` wasn't null (even `console.log` can be misleading about it).

However I would suggest to instead use the inbuilt `onScroll` prop on the component you are attaching the `ref` to, and give it a callback to handle the scroll. That way you don't need to attach it manually in the useEffect hook where you are forgetting to remove it on unmount(memory leak problems).

---

```js
interface IProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  getScrollTop: (scrollTop: number) => whatever;
  // Your other Props
}

const ScrollComponent: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  children,
  getScrollTop,
  // Your other props
}): JSX.Element => {
  const handleScroll = (e: React.UIEvent<HTMLElement>): void => {
    e.stopPropagation() // Handy if you want to prevent event bubbling to scrollable parent
    console.log({
      event: e,
      target: e.target, // Note 1* scrollTop is undefined on e.target
      currentTarget: e.currentTarget,
      scrollTop: e.currentTarget.scrollTop,
    });

    const { scrollTop } = e.currentTarget;
    getScrollTop(scrollTop);
  };

  return (
  <div
    // I am assuming you were referencing your scroller as follows.
    // ref={scroller}
    onScroll={handleScroll} // Use the onScroll prop instead.
  >
    {children}
  </div>
  );
};
```

`Note *1:` **scrollTop** wont be available on `e.target.scrollTop`, much as you can see in in the `console.log`, but on `e.currentTarget.scrollTop`, since [currentTarget](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11508#issuecomment-256045682) calls the element on which the event handler is attached to.

Comment: Thank you for your additional solution. It's exactly what I wanted to accomplish and it's much cleaner than a ref.

Comment: @AndresSepulveda, these days though, you better `debounce` that scroll or use the `Intersection Observer` api because the scroll event fires waaayyyy too many times.

Comment: @iamcastelli IntersectionObserver doesnt react immediatelly, so sometimes its efficient but slow in terms of page interactions

Comment: "Event" is more appropriate for scroll handling. Typescript says "Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'UIEvent<HTMLElement>".

Answer (score 5):

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
      const e = event as WheelEvent;
      // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me -

```
//register the scroll event listener callback function
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
    }
  })
```

```
// scroll event callback function
  const onScroll = (e: Event) => {
    const window = e.currentTarget as Window
    //... rest of you function
  }
```

Make sure to include dom lib in `tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": [
        "dom",
        "dom.iterable",
        ...
      ],
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const onScroll = (event: UIEvent) => {
      const target = event.target as HTMLElement;

      if (target && target.scrollTop + target.clientHeight + 1 >= target.scrollHeight) {
        // do the magic
      }
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

So, I'm just going to expand on the answer from [@ManjuPrabhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/985406/manju-prabhu)

`Header.tsx`

```
const Header: React.FC<IHeader> = () => {
  const [scrolling, setScrolling] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    };
  });

  const onScroll = (e: Event) => {
    const window = e.currentTarget as Window;
    let currentPosition = window.scrollY;
    currentPosition > 0 ? setScrolling(true) : setScrolling(false);
  };

  return (
    <div
      // clsx is a npm package for conditional classes
      className={clsx('navbar sticky top-0 z-50', { 
        'shadow-2xl': scrolling,
      })}
    >
    Header content
    </div>
  );
};
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": [
        "dom",
        "dom.iterable",
        ...
      ],
```