# Using React Hooks To Update w/ Scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to control the visibility of a React Component based on whether an individual is scrolling down on the component. The visibility is passed into the `Fade` element as the "in" property.

I've set up a listener using the UseEffect Hook, which adds the listener onMount. The actual onScroll function is supposed to update the scrollTop state (which is the current value of the height to the top of the page) and then the scrolling state (which compares the event's scroll to the top of the page with the previous state, and if the first is greater than the second, returns true).

However, for some reason the setScrollTop hook isn't working, and the scrolling state continues to stay at 0.

What am I doing wrong? Here's the full component:

```
export const Header = (props) => {

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [scrolling, setScrolling] = useState(false);
  const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = useState(0);

  const onScroll = (e) => {
    setScrollTop(e.target.documentElement.scrollTop);
    setScrolling(e.target.documentElement.scrollTop > scrollTop);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  },[]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(scrollTop);
  }, [scrollTop])

  return (
   <Fade in={!scrolling}>
      <AppBar className={classes.header} position="fixed">

  ....
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You're missing the dependencies in your hook. Try this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = e => {
      setScrollTop(e.target.documentElement.scrollTop);
      setScrolling(e.target.documentElement.scrollTop > scrollTop);
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  }, [scrollTop]);
```

By moving `onScroll` inside the `useEffect`, you don't need to track it on the hook's dependencies, however since it uses `scrollTop` from the component's scope, you'll need to add it.

Alternatively, if for some reason you don't want to move `onScroll` definition inside the `useEffect`, you'll need to wrap `onScroll` in `useCallback` and track it in `useEffect`'s dependency array.

In general I'd recommend adding `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` to your ESlint rules

Also it's a good idea to remove the event listener in cleanup function.

Comment: How would you type this in Typescript?

Comment: @HarrisonCramer et al, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56164315/how-to-describe-type-scroll-events

Answer (score 9):

Or you can use window.pageYOffset. It's a bit more understandable for me that way:

```
const [scrolling, setScrolling] = useState(false);
  const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    function onScroll() {
      let currentPosition = window.pageYOffset; // or use document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      if (currentPosition > scrollTop) {
        // downscroll code
        setScrolling(false);
      } else {
        // upscroll code
        setScrolling(true);
      }
      setScrollTop(currentPosition <= 0 ? 0 : currentPosition);
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  }, [scrollTop]);
```