# React OnChange Reloads DOM everytime

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a Functional React component with Form in it. The form has multiple Text inputs

```
  <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
  
    <div className="mb-3">
        <label className="form-label">Role</label>
        <input type="text"  onChange={(e)=>setRole(e.target.value)} className="form-control" id="role" />
    </div>
    
    <div className="mb-3">
        <label className="form-label">Facebook Handle</label>
        <input type="url" onChange={(e)=>setFacebookHandle(e.target.value)} className="form-control" id="FBHandle" />
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</Form>
```

I am using React useState hook and handling onChange Event. Below is the code for the same

```
const [role,setRole] = useState('')
const [facebookHandle,setFacebookHandle] = useState('')
```

Whenever I enter the value in the text field, The DOM seems to be reloading and scrolling the page to the top (I have few input Fields and labels above). It is creating a problem as the page scrolls up every time I enter some value.  I tried using preventDefault() function. that doesn't help too! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved:

The problem is due to the double inclusion of my Navbar in the nested components. Somewhere there I am setting window scroll-Y to 0 which in turn firing up every time.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds that what is happening is that when you change the `role` by using `setRole()` the component re-renders (happens when a state updates) . So it is as if it refreshes and then the page returns to the top. So you need to save the scroll as a state (you can save it to - the distance from the form to the top of the page) and when the page re-renders, use `useEffect(()=> {set the scroll position}, [role])` to restore the scroll position.

To get scroll position you can use `window.pageYOffset`

You could also use a scroll event listener to update your scroll position to the current one, maybe this helps:
[Using React Hooks To Update w/ Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57453141/using-react-hooks-to-update-w-scroll)